# org.hibernate.TransientObjectException during Criteria.list()

Tags: java, hibernate

I have seen posts all over the internet that talk about how to fix the TransientObjectExceptions during save/update/delete but I am having this problem when calling list on my Criteria.

I have two objects A and B.  A has a field named b which is of type B.  In my mapping b is mapped as a many-to-one.  This all runs in a larger persistence framework (the framework is kind of like Core Data) and so I don't use any cascades in my hibernate mappings since cascades are handled at a higher level.

This is the interesting code surrounding my criteria:

```
A a = new A();
B b = new B();
a.setB(b);

session.save("B", b); // Actually handled by the higher level
session.save("A", a); // framework, this is just for clarity

// transaction committed and session closed
...
// new session opened

Criteria criteria = session.createCriteria(A.class);
criteria.add(Restrictions.eq("b", b));
List<?> objects = criteria.list();
```

Basically I am looking for all objects of type A such that A.b equals a particular instance of b (I actually tried restructuring a query so that I was passing in the id of b just to make sure that b wasn't causing me problems).

Here is the stack trace that occurs when I call criteria.list():

```
org.hibernate.TransientObjectException: object references an unsaved transient instance - save the transient instance before flushing: B
at org.hibernate.engine.ForeignKeys.getEntityIdentifierIfNotUnsaved(ForeignKeys.java:244)
at org.hibernate.type.EntityType.getIdentifier(EntityType.java:449)
at org.hibernate.type.ManyToOneType.nullSafeSet(ManyToOneType.java:141)
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.bindPositionalParameters(Loader.java:1769)
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.bindParameterValues(Loader.java:1740)
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.prepareQueryStatement(Loader.java:1612)
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQuery(Loader.java:717)
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQueryAndInitializeNonLazyCollections(Loader.java:270)
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2294)
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.listIgnoreQueryCache(Loader.java:2172)
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.list(Loader.java:2167)
at org.hibernate.loader.criteria.CriteriaLoader.list(CriteriaLoader.java:119)
at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.list(SessionImpl.java:1706)
at org.hibernate.impl.CriteriaImpl.list(CriteriaImpl.java:347)
```

Here is my mapping:

> `<class entity-name="A" lazy="false">`
>       `<tuplizer entity-mode="dynamic-map" class="MyTuplizer" />`
>       `<id type="long" column="id">`
>           `<generator class="native" />`
>       `</id>`
>       `<many-to-one name="b" entity-name="B" column="b_id" lazy="false" />`
>       `</class>`
>   
>       `<class entity-name="B" lazy="false">`
>       `<tuplizer entity-mode="dynamic-map" class="MyTuplizer" />`
>       `<id type="long" column="id">`
>       `<generator class="native" />`
>       `</id>`
>       `</class>`

Can anyone help me figure out why I would be getting a TransientObjectException during a fetch?  Preferably I would like to find a solution that does not rely on cascades since they tend to mask problems that occur in the higher level framework.

Comment: Could you show where the object `b` comes from in your code? Is it persistent?

Comment: Peter you are a genius!  The session where I saved b is long gone by this point and so I have to update b in the new session right before I call list on the criteria.  Please add an answer so I can award you the credit.

Comment: Thanks :-) I added my answer in the meantime.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that `b` was made persistent in another session, which is closed and the query is created in a new session. When a session is closed, all objects in its persistence context become *detached*. If you want to later reuse them in another session, you need to re-attach them to that session first:

```
session.update(b);
```

Quote from the Hibernate book:

> The `update()` operation
>   on the Session reattaches the detached object to the persistence context and
>   schedules an `SQL UDPATE`. Hibernate must assume that the client modified the
>   object while it was detached. (Otherwise, if you’re certain that it hasn’t been modified,
>   a `lock()` would be sufficient.) The persistence context is flushed automatically
>   when the second transaction in the conversation commits, and any
>   modifications to the once detached and now persistent object are synchronized
>   with the database.
>
> The `saveOrUpdate()` method is in practice more useful than `update()`,
>   `save()`, or `lock()`: In complex conversations, you don’t know if the item is in
>   detached state or if it’s new and transient and must be saved. The automatic
>   state-detection provided by `saveOrUpdate()` becomes even more useful when you
>   not only work with single instances, but also want to reattach or persist a network
>   of connected objects and apply cascading options.

Note that there is also a `merge()` method, for cases when the same entity has been loaded into the new persistence context before the older detached instance could be re-attached. In this case, you have two physically distinct instances representing the same entity, thus they should be merged to avoid a `NonUniqueObjectException`.

Comment: Again thanks Peter!  I had been pounding my head on this for days until you pointed this out.

Comment: I had the same problem when I tried your solution I started getting: }: org.springframework.dao.DuplicateKeyException: a different object with the same identifier value was already associated with the session:

Answer (score 0):

Another easy way accomplish the same is to use the attribute cascade=all on the collection mapping of child class from within the parent class mapping. Here's how the mapping looks

```
<class entity-name="A" lazy="false">
<tuplizer entity-mode="dynamic-map" class="MyTuplizer" />
<id type="long" column="id">
<generator class="native" />
</id>
<many-to-one name="b" entity-name="B" column="b_id" lazy="false" cascade="all" />
</class>

<class entity-name="B" lazy="false">
<tuplizer entity-mode="dynamic-map" class="MyTuplizer" />
<id type="long" column="id">
<generator class="native" />
</id>
</class>
```

Comment: Except that I explicitly stated in the question that I do not want to use cascades for the reasons mentioned in the question.

Comment: I agree and respect your explanation at the top. But cause this blog search-able over net, I wanted to suggest a different scenario and when cascades are not to be handled by code, it can be done this way. Will modify my part as well.

Answer (score 0):

Since you have insert data such as in persist(),save() in hibernate..But the above error is you have just do merge() and others method which can perform the update information.